# ICS ROM with no Slovenian language

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, languages

I bought HTC desire S in Slovenia and it has installed karnel ROM:

```
    RUU_SAGA_ICS_35_S_HTC_EU_14.01.401.2_20.76.30.0835_3831.19.00.110_275068
```

This ROM do not offer Slovenian language. So i need help what to do to have Slovenian android version. It is not metter even if it is 2.3 version. Only that it has official android with Slovenian language.

Any idea how to use my device with Slovenian language?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing a custom ROM with support for the language you need. I think CyanogenMod might be a good try since it's usually very stable and close to "stock" ROMs of Android. You can find the stable CyanogenMod version for HTC Desire S [here](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?type=stable&device=saga).

Rooting and flashing ROMs on your device might require some work on your device if it's not rooted, or if it's rooted it might be quite simple. Since you don't offer any information on whether you are rooted or not, here's some resources for you to look up:

- [Installing a custom ROM on the HTC Desire S [HD] Step-by-step tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btTmTj9Nq3g)
- [How to S-Off and Root the HTC Desire S, Sensation, Wildfire, Evo, Flyer HD - A step-by-step tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvg0i8in96M)

All of this is of course assuming that your current Android version *does not support changing the language*. You might want to look in your menus just to make sure. If it's not there, you need to get another ROM.

If you have any questions, please comment on this answer and I'll try to expand on it accordingly.

Comment: Phone is S-On and not-routed. i have prevoius build number 2.10.401.8 CL156318 RELEASE KEYS if this gives any information. Otherwise rooting seems to complicated routing for me while I am not such phone expert and i do not want something goes wrong. This ROM do not offer Slovenian language. Is there any possibility to find official previous ROM??? and how can i install official ROM?
Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: You can always look at HTC's website or contact them to get some kind of update software.

Comment: Hi back,
I just found ROM that was previously installed on my HTC desires s and there is new question: How can i install now RUU_Saga_S_HTC_Europe_2.10.401.8_Radio_20.4801.30.0822U_3822.10.08.04_M_release_225161_signed so this ROM which has slovenian language will overwrite ROM that i have now? I hoe there is some easy way- and it is not need to root phone?

Comment: You probably need to root your phone and install a custom bootloader (CWM Recovery for example)

Comment: I found a solution for all languages issue: on google play is  app: MoreLocale2 which offer many languages. This app change language of your UI on Android phone.